# How to config `middleware` in connect server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, stylus, node.js-connect

I am using `connect` server with `serve-static` for my `angular` app. according to the `stylus` doc they ask to use the `middleware` (https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/middleware.html) to utalize the `.styl` file. i tried  but not working.

In the connect server doc `https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#readme` shows some way which i am not understand.

here is my code :

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.middleware({
   src: __dirname + '/css',
   dest: __dirname + '/css'
 });

function compile(str, path) {
   return stylus(str)
     .set('filename', 'tcp.styl')
     .set('compress', true)
     .use(nib())
     .import('nib');
 }

app.use(serveStatic("app"));
app.listen(5000, function () {console.log("HI");});
```

Any one help me to config the mid-ware here?

the error i am getting right now is :

```
D:\Projects\TCP>node server.js
D:\Projects\TCP\server.js:6
app.middleware({
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\TCP\server.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

D:\Projects\TCP>
```

**update**

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
    stylus = require('stylus');

var app = connect();

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src     : __dirname + '/app/css',
    dest    : __dirname + '/app/css',
    force   : true,
    compile : function(str, path) {
      return stylus(str, path)
        .set('tcp', path)
        .set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true);
    }
}));

app.use(serveStatic("app"));
app.listen(5000, function () {console.log("HI", __dirname);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stylus middleware is not shipped anymore by default.
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/0680f226f6bf7cc0c9e21a5a54a83c2deda5c4b4/History.md#057--2011-02-01

You can still use it like

```
var stylus = require('stylus');

...

app.use(stylus.middleware(...));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am out of error now. but on change of my `styl` file nothing happen with html. how to properly sync the `.styl` file and each time change how to update?

Comment: the 'force' option will recompile every time

Comment: Still not get any ouput. what is this part ` compile : function(str, path) {
      return stylus(str, path)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true);
    }` is i need to give the `filename` as what is the file i requried? say `abc.css'

Comment: Can you see my question on the `update` section and correct me please?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the src and dest being the same

Comment: Now i changed to different folders, still getting same, nothing compiles